# Inserting an element into vector in the middle

Tags: c++, vector

Is there an way of inserting/deleting an element from the vectors other than the following..

1. The formal method of using 'push_back'
2. Using 'find()' in this way... find(v.begin(), v.end(), int)

I have read some where that inserting in the middle can be achieved by inclusive insertion/deletion.

So, is it really possible?

Comment: There's an `insert` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding to middle of std::vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800701/adding-to-middle-of-stdvector)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [std::vector::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/); however, note that this operation is O([.size()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size)). If your code needs to perform insertions in the middle frequently, you may want to switch to a linked-list structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
Is there an way of inserting/deleting an element from the vectors other than the following
```

Yes, you can use [std::vector::insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to insert element at a specified position.

Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, inserting elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to move all the elements that were after position to their new positions. This is generally an inefficient operation compared to the one performed for the same operation by other kinds of sequence containers (such as std::list).

`std::vector` is standard container, you could apply standard `STL algorithms` on it.

Answer (score 0):

[vector::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) seems to be what you want.